# Facing too much Insufficient Memory exception while working with memory mapped-IO files

Tags: c#, large-files, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapped-io

I am trying to create memory-mapped IO files for having sized ( 1-100 GB ) files. These files will contain random data that will be generated during the process.

So, I am trying to generate partitions dynamically by considering the available memory of the system.

Following is the source code.

```
public class RandomLinesGenerator
{
    private static string GenerateRandomTextLine(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        Random random = new Random();
        int length = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);

        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    public static byte[] GetRandomBytes(long desiredByteCount, int prefixIntMinValue, int prefixIntMaxValue)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        long currentByteCount = 0;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while (currentByteCount < desiredByteCount)
        {
            // Generate a random integer
            int randomNumber = random.Next(prefixIntMinValue, prefixIntMaxValue + 1);

            // Generate a random line
            string randomLine = $"{randomNumber} {GenerateRandomTextLine(1, 150)}";

            // Calculate the byte count of the line
            long lineByteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(randomLine) + Environment.NewLine.Length;

            // If adding the line exceeds the desired byte count, break the loop
            if (currentByteCount + lineByteCount > desiredByteCount)
            {
                break;
            }

            builder.AppendLine(randomLine); // ==> This is the line where the exception is occurring of Insufficient memory..

            currentByteCount += lineByteCount;
        }

        var bytes =  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
        builder.Clear();

        return bytes;
    }
}

public class MemoryMappedIOTechnique
{
    private static readonly string _fileLocation = Path.Combine("Resources", "files");
    private long GetPartitionSize(long totalFileSize)
    {
        var partitionSize = (long)Math.Ceiling((long)new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes").NextValue() * 0.8);
        return Math.Min(partitionSize ,totalFileSize);
    }

    public void Execute(int sizeInGb)
    {
        try
        {    

            long totalBytesToWrite = sizeInGb * Convert.ToInt64(1024 * 1024 * 1024);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(_fileLocation, $"file_{sizeInGb}-GB.txt");
            long partitionSize = GetPartitionSize(totalBytesToWrite);

            using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Create, "mmf", totalBytesToWrite))
            {
                long offset = 0;
                long partitions = (totalBytesToWrite / partitionSize);

                for (var partition = 0; partition < partitions; partition++)
                {
                    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, partitionSize))
                    {
                        var randomBytes = RandomLinesGenerator.GetRandomBytes(partitionSize, 10, 2500);
                        accessor.WriteArray(0, randomBytes, 0, randomBytes.Length);
                        offset += partitionSize;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now I am getting an exception while I just called the function for providing 2 GB. First, it is taking more amount of time and the other it causes the exception of 'Insufficient memory
I could see that on Task Manager, almost 3 GB is still free.

Can anybody guide me on how to change the source code to handle safely all types of cases without having insufficient memory exception cases? Need to generate ( 1, 2, ...-100 GB ) files.

I am completely new to Memory-mapped IO and have very little knowledge about this whole topic.

Comment: Could it be due to memory fragmentation? So even though there's free 3 GB of RAM, there's no contiguous segment of 2 GB long? If it feels very sluggish, it's possible that the OS when trying to free up the RAM end up pushing various services and app to the pagefile that would end up slowing down everything because they have to be swapped back to RAM all the time.

Comment: Just use a database, already. You already had many issues creating those insanely huge files. Why not just use something that is _designed_ to hold insanely huge volume of data?

Comment: @Martheen : Yeah , could be. But the above code is correct? Might be I need to change the partition size ? or something else?

Comment: @Fildor : I am sorry , I have a task to create these inanely large amount ofo files first and then need to sort them out using ExternalMergeSort.

Comment: I know. And that's really not smart when you could use more appropriate tools.

Comment: @Fildor : If you could help regarding the source code to adjust in order to solve the problem, that would be very nice.